# Merge/Copy linked contacts

Tags: contacts, sync, owncloud

I hope this is the right place to ask my question.

On my android phone I have my contacts synchronized with NextCloud (CardDAV). Now, many contacts are linked/connected with other (same) contacts from social networks, providing more data. So far, so good.

As I would like to have a "unique exhaustive" contacts list that I also use on other devices (PC, online, or maybe another phone), I would like to merge/copy the additional data from the linked contacts into my existing contacts lists (which is then synchronized with my cloud/cardDAV).

So, the questions are: - is there any easy way to do this? - without giving my contacts to google or any other shady app? - preferrably with the option to chose on which data "wins" (like, own nextcloud contacts always win facebook data)

Thanks for any advice!